# Set-ItemProperty for each Application associated with IIS WebSite

Tags: powershell, iis

The following powershell successfully updates the EnabledProtocols property for my WebSite "Test Services"

```
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\sites\Test Services' -name EnabledProtocols -Value "http,net.tcp,net.pipe"
```

Does anyone know the syntax for setting the EnabledProtocols property for each WebApplication associated with the WebSite "Test Services"?

Comment: Are there any Powershell\IIS gurus here that might know the syntax for this?

Comment: Could anyone please help?